# Classifying points in subspaces

Tags: r, classification

I have a set of points in 5D and I am building a classifier. There are five classes.

One interesting property of the data is that points in each class tend to be located in, or near, a 1D, 2D or 3D subspace. The subspaces associated with each class are not unique (that is, multiple classes can share a subspace) and are not known a priori.

Are there classifiers -- perhaps with R code -- that would somehow make use of this structure?

Comment: Yes!, Have a look at SIMCA (package rrcovHD for both classical [CSimaca] and robust [RSimca] versions)

Comment: @user603: Thanks! I think this deserves to be an answer. :-)